# Ошибка tasker: приложение не имеет необходимых разрешений

Tags: nfc

У меня установлено приложение NFC Tools, я хочу связать с Tasker`ом.
По итогу у меня возникает такая ошибка: "Ошибка tasker: приложение не имеет необходимых разрешений",
как это исправить?
P.S. Я знаю что проблема в разрешениях, проблема в том что я выдал разрешение через ADB и разрешил внешний доступ. Пожалуйса не судите строго, я не смог найти ответ в Google...

Comment: У меня такая же ерунда. Причём в самом Таскере задача работает. Вы нашли причину? Поделитесь успехом!

Comment: 2021 год. Аналогичная проблема, пока решить не удалось. (